# Is there any good out-of-the-box Expert System Engine?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, expert-system

I am looking into [Expert Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system) - just wondering if there are any good engines (commercial or open) available to facilitate development of a custom expert system (rather than building the whole thing from scratch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, the classic (free) expert systems shell is [CLIPS](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/).

-m

Answer (score 1):

In the business world these are typically called [Rules Engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine).  I've worked with the one from Haley Systems - they were acquired by Oracle last year (http://www.oracle.com/haley/index.html)

Another one that I've seen is [ILog](http://www.ilog.com/)

Also, for Net there's one called [inrule](http://www.inrule.com/).

Answer (score 0):

computer associates has an aion business rule system http://www.ca.com/us/products/product.aspx?id=250

dont know how many ppl use it nowadays...

Answer (score 0):

The best rule-processing system that I know of is JBoss Rules (also known as Drools). You can integrate program components in the rules, integrate rule-bases in program components, and even build / modify rule-bases on the fly.

You might also be interested in a system conceived from addressing the limitations of rule-based expert systems called High Level Logic (HLL).
http://highlevellogic.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) is excellent for writing expert systems.

Answer (score 0):

[Jess](http://herzberg.ca.sandia.gov/jess/) should also be considered. Very good support on the mailing list.